# My implementation accepts only URLClassLoader, may I be less restrictive in my method signature?

Tags: java, programming-practices, api, methods

I wrote a Java API that accepts `ClassLoader`s as parameter, even though it won't accept any `ClassLoader` that isn't a `URLClassLoader` (because I'm only interested in the `URLClassLoader::getURLs()` method):

```
/**
 * @throws NullPointerException if classLoader is null.
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if classLoader is not a URLClassLoader
 */
public void addClassLoader(ClassLoader classLoader) {
  if (!(classLoader instanceof URLClassLoader)) {
    if (classLoader == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("classLoader must not be null");
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("classLoader must be a URLClassLoader");
    }
  }
  this.classLoaders.add((URLClassLoader)classLoader);
}
```

I did this for several reasons:

- adding a `ClassLoader` is a nice-to-have feature, not a must-have one: my API accepts several kinds of inputs;
- the vast majority of `ClassLoader`s that users will want to give as parameters are indeed `URLClassLoader`s (from custom ones to web-app ones);
- the `ClassLoader` isn't a very well known API and `URLClassLoader` is rather obscure and users shouldn't have to learn the `ClassLoader` capabilities in order to use my API;
- casting a `ClassLoader` to `URLClassLoader` makes the client code less readable.

However I know that I should probably enforce the fact that I will only accept `URLClassLoader` in the method because it makes sense from my implementation details.

My question is: given all that is it OK to leave my method signature as `addClassLoader(ClassLoader)` and not `addClassLoader(URLClassLoader)`?

Comment: Why not go further and just take `Object` as your input, and throw on anything that isn't a `URLClassLoader`? I mean, no casting, ever, simplest API, vast majority of entities in client code are `Object`s. What can go wrong?

Comment: If you care only for `URLClassLoader::getURLS()` why not requiring a collection of URLs as parameter ? It would reduce coupling inside your class and make (potential) tests easier to write.

Comment: @Spotted I have this use case: "my API accepts several kinds of inputs"

Comment: Which kind of inputs ?

Comment: `URL`, `URI`, `Path`,`File`, etc. (and their `Iterable<X>` version). Everything that is like a resource container in Java.

Comment: Do you treat all these inputs in the same way later in code ? (for example, load a file at the URL/URI/Path/File destination)

Comment: @Spotted No: the resource collecting mechanism is specific to the resource container passed in parameter. For instance, I use the `(URL)ClassLoader` to load the resource itself, but I need the `getURLs()` to index its content first. This is not an XY problem. If I offer the `(URL)ClassLoader` possibility, I really use it for all it has to offer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's absolutely not OK.

A signature is a promise. You're breaking that promise. The fact that most of the time there will be no repercussions is a point *against* you, not for you: defects that cause problems *rarely, unpredictably and in special situations* are **much worse** than blatant ones. Blatant defects immediately cause problems and are rejected bu the community. Subtle, unlikely defects can make it all the way into production and into critical systems before being noticed.

TL;DR Don't go out of your way to create subtle defects.

Answer (score 4):

I would enforce the URLClassLoader. If you accept a ClassLoader and you throw an exception.

My first thought was, that you hurt the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) but it is the other way around: You don't accept the more general case.

But this is like beating the type system with your feet. Instead of letting your type system check your program while compile time you do it on runtime while you have no advantages.

I just created some tests (see below) to get the problem. It feels very unnatural that the third test is failing.

As an user, I would expect, that the type system should catch the third (failing) test case. In fact I just started the debugger to dig in to reason about.

This should not the case: **The interface should should express the intention of the method** and if you look at the the **methods body, it should be the same as you expected to see**. This is not not the case here.

```
@Test
void shouldTakeUrlClassLoader() {
    ClassLoaderExample uut = new ClassLoaderExample();
    uut.addClassLoader(new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{}));
}

@Test
void shouldTakeSubtypeOfUrlClassLoader() {
    ClassLoaderExample uut = new ClassLoaderExample();
    uut.addClassLoader(new SpecializedLoader(new URL[]{}));
}

@Test
void shouldTakeClassLoaderAsArgument() {
    ClassLoaderExample uut = new ClassLoaderExample();
    uut.addClassLoader(new ClassLoaderStub());
}

class ClassLoaderStub extends ClassLoader {}

class SpecializedLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    SpecializedLoader(URL[] urls) {
        super(urls);
    }
}
```

[EDIT]. The third case fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: classLoader must be a URLClassLoader`